# How to remove 'before' key from payload generated by debezium event for updates in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, apache-hudi

For every update in SQL server, debezium generates event payload with 'after' and 'before'. I want to get rid of 'before' without flattening the payload.

**Use case**:

I am using debezium with Kafka and hudi and have created a data lake, I don't need delete operations so I have skipped delete operations.

So I want to reduce the size of payload to half by eliminating the 'before' part so how we can achieve this?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, used existing transforms. Following transformation works like a charm

> transforms=ReplaceField
> transforms.ReplaceField.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value
> transforms.ReplaceField.exclude=before

Answer (score 0):

The only way to remove `after` with Debezium connector is [to flatten](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.9/transformations/event-flattening.html). You can "add back" the event metadata using `add.fields` config.

Alternative solutions include using Kafka Streams/KSQL/Spark/Flink etc. to select/expand the individual fields you're interested in from the Debezium source topic, write to an intermediate topic with the data you want to sink, then have the Hudi consumer read that topic.

Comment: After flattening, does it work with Hudi? Hudi expects data in specific format or it should work after flattening?

Comment: I don't have Hudi experience. If it expects a very specific format, then you need to use stream processor to get data that way, which Connect/Debezium may not support